# Use oauth2 authentication for the main app and basic auth for the management endpoints in spring boot?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring Boot to build a REST Api which I can secure with Oauth2 (using spring-security-oauth2).

I want to manage a separate authentication and authorization schema for the actuator management endpoints (metrics, health, etc.).

And I want the management endpoints to run on a different port (management.port=8081 in application.properties)

I've been reading quite a lot but couldn't find a way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can't separate endpoints by port. If the actuator management endpoints and the management endpoints are on the same component, the Spring Boot container (Tomcat) will launch that whole component on one port.

What you are saying can maybe be achieved by a proxy. You would map some urls on the proxy to internally correspond with the urls on your component.